# Reading certificates installed on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I have installed a certificate on my iPhone. I want to read the certificate details using an application that i can run on iPhone. Can anyone help me in this.

Thanks

Lakshman

Answer (score 0):

You can view basic info about the provisioning profiles and developer certificates you have installed via:

`Settings → General → Profiles`

I'm unaware of any way to get more details without a jailbreak. But I'm a bit of a novice, so I bet someone else out there might have a tip.